# Updating rails 2 routing to rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

Hi I'm stuck with a little bit of rails routing,

How should this look in rails 3 routing?:

```
map.resources :books do |book|  
    book.resources :comments, :only => :create  
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resources :books do
  resources :comments, :only => :create
end
```

will do it. More infos about Rails 3 routing at Ruby on Rails Guides: [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: That's great, thanks, works like a charm. Thanks for the link as well it is something i have to understand better, I'm just under pressure with a college deadline. Thanks again!